# Howto set Range to third Heading1 style match?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document where I want to start start searching in section 3 to the end of the document and bold text based on my user-defined style since other styles used may contain the same word I don't want to bold - including the possibility of the Heading/section.

I do have VBA code that works by finding my user-defined style throughout the document and bolding it for one style match only. However, the .Style in the .find doesn't allow one to specify a wildcard style i.e. my user-defined style set of "Requirement1 thru Requirement9" which are based off the Heading1-9 style. I assume I'll have to create a for loop outside of the "with" that finds my user-defined style that is passed one at a time to bold the text to match one style at a time i.e Requirement1 thru Requirement9.  Is there a better way? see code below.

The next issue is to focus the search of this text to bold to start in a particular section to the end of the document. For me, its section 3 to the end of the document or till it encounters another style defined as Appendix1 and stop. I do have user-defined styles Appendix1 thru Appendix9 that are also based off of Heading1-9. The reason to search on a style as a starting point is because these other sections before section3, or descriptive text in Section 3 and beyond may contain the word I'm trying to bold - which I don't want to do except when my particular user-defined style Requirment1-9 was applied that is used in section 3 and beyond. In trying to implement this part before doing the word searching and bolding part, I've been searching based on the "Heading1" style and when I found the third one, I know I'm in section 3. I can't use the VBA "sections" search since it includes all the subsections of a document which can vary from document to document and specifying sections.item(3) doesn't mean I'll get the third section of my document that corresponds to the third Heading1 style.

Since I'm not that adept at the various VBA sections,paragraphs,sentences, characters and everything else when applying the "range" either before, after, or both on any of these (never seems to work the way one expects. Even the VBA hint tools says one can do it, but runtime says error) I've started with the specifying the start/end of the whole activedocument.range. Then I perform a ".find" of the "Heading1" style in a for loop three times which does find them. I then try to assign the last Heading1 found range value as the start value to use in the next embedded "find" that will search and apply the bold to the "Requirement1" style. (May need to create a loop to search Requirement1-9 styles as stated above). To help me know where I'm at, I'm trying to dump via debug.print the range position, but it dumps the all whole document text to the debug window and not the integer value I thought I'd get. Whats the issue with doing this? I've even tried to use a selection.range and dump the retrieved text to the debug.print window without success. It makes it worse since the processing timing seems to run forever. The wdFindStop doesn't force the find to stop on the third find either.

So how to:
a). find and dump the range position to the debug window along with the text at this position. Both the number and text will tell me where I'm at.
c).  How to assign the range position based on find of the third "Heading1" position in the document so that that the second "with" can search and apply the bolding to the text I want to bold.
d). How to do a wildcard search on the .Style user-defined Requirement1-9 style instead of having to create a for loop to search one at a time?

The following is the VBA code I have written.

```
Attribute VB_Name = "BoldMustShall2_M"
Option Explicit

Public Sub BoldMustShall2()

'  If  .Parent.Bold = True is used with wdReplaceall, the whole
' document is bolded even when the sentence doesn't have any of the words
' being searched for.
Dim myRange, rngSel As Range
Dim oDoc As Word.Document

Dim pos1, pos2 As Long
Dim numchars As Long


Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set rngSel = Selection.Range


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set the starting Heading to search as Section 3
pos1 = oDoc.Range.Start
pos2 = oDoc.Range.End


Set myRange = oDoc.Range(Start:=pos1, End:=pos2)
'Another way is to find the "Heading1" style and set the range start to the third one found which is section 3.
'Counting Word sections can vary alot so its not the best way.
'The same would apply if Appendix1 style is used and assuming that requiremens start in the third one.

Debug.Print "My Start Range " + myRange

With myRange
    .TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = False  ' don't want to search fieldcodes for must/shall
    .TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = False  ' don't want to search hiddentext for must/shall

' Get the range position for Heading1 style for section 3 of PRD.
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ReqHDR As Range
    Dim bFind As Boolean
    
    
    
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    '.Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Style = "Heading1"
    
    'Loop three times for Style
    For i = 1 To 3 Step 1
        'bFind = .Execute
        .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop
     If .Found = True Then
        rngSel = oDoc.Range 'This should be the current position in the Document for the requirements.
     ' When found it outputs the message once
         Debug.Print "Found a Heading1 style "
         .Replacement.Font.Size = 20
         
     End If
     '.Wrap = wdFindStop
     Next i
     
  
  End With
  Debug.Print "End of Heading1 Search "
  
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 12
    .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    '.Style = "Requirement1"   ' A loop is needed to cycle thru all the Requirement1-9 styles. No wildcard.
    '.Style = wdStyleNormal
          
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"  ' This is the contents of the find what box in word.
                              ' In this case the .find.text "must"  statement.
                              ' Alternate is to specify "must" or "shall" but this
                              ' would require two replace.text statements instead of
                              ' just this one. The ^& is a special command that eliminates
                              ' the need to set the replacement.Text info.
    
    '.Text = "must"
    .Execute FindText:="must", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     If .Found = True Then
     ' When found it outputs the message once
         Debug.Print "Found one or more must "
     End If
     
    '.Text = "shall"
    .Execute FindText:="shall", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    If .Found = True Then
    ' When found it outputs the message once
        Debug.Print "Found one or more shall "
     End If
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Debug.Print "Completed searching for must/shall in document."
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you narrow your question to just one issue at a time. And provide some sample data and screenshots .Also remember to accept the answers of previous questions if they helped you indeed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, when you refer to 'Sections', you're referring to parts of your document delineated by Section breaks, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Range(.Sections(3).Range.Start, .Range.End)
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Style = "Appendix1"
      .Execute
    End With
    Rng.End = .Start
  End With
  With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Replacement.Style = "Strong"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Text = "must"
    For i = 1 To 9
      .Style = "Requirement" & i
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
    .Text = "shall"
    For i = 1 To 9
      .Style = "Requirement" & i
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that, instead of using hard formatting for the replacement, I've simply applied Word's built-in 'Strong' Style. Your own code should use a Style, too, whether it's Word's 'Strong' Style or another character Style of your own definition.